# Double-Clicking Item in ListView

Tags: c#, double-click

So I added a list view, and I am displaying 3 columns of strings in each. I also have the full row select on. I want to be able to double click on one of the rows, and have it return the string in the 3rd column. I've tried to look everywhere for a solution to this, but so far nothing comes up.

My code so far is:

```
private void listView_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(songList.SelectedItems[2].ToString());
}
```

Yet it returns an error saying "InvalidArgument=Value of '2' is not valid for 'index'.
Parameter name: index"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try:

```
if (songList.SelectedItems.Count > 0) 
{
    ListViewItem item = songList.SelectedItems[0];
    string s_you_want = item.SubItems[1].Text;
}
```

Taken a `ListViewItem`, you can take *columns values* using `SubItems[]` property.

Answer (score 0):

SelectedItems returns a SelectedListViewItemCollection and with the indexer you are accessing elements in this collection, i.e. ListViewItems, not the columns. this means that if you have a single row selected the collection contains only one item, and trying to access the third one gives you the error.

Try (edit according to Marco's comment):

```
songList.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[1].Text
```

Comment: So, do you have any idea of how I would go about getting the third item from a selected row? I'm fairly new to this.

Comment: If I remember well, you should take `SubItems[1]` to take thew third column. Infact the first is taken as `Text`, while others are taken with `SubItems[]` property with index starting from 0.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you hould bound not your listView to doubleClick event, but listViewItem. sender will have DataContext, from which you can get your third column.

Answer (score 0):

How do you fill the `ListView`? Wihtout knowing this, it's difficult to help. May be you could try this:

Set a breakpoint in this line:

```
MessageBox.Show(songList.SelectedItems[2].ToString());
```

As soon as the debugger hits the breakpoint you could select `songList` and hit Shift-F9.
Now you can explore the `songList` and check yourself how to get the string of the third column.

Comment: `songList.SelectedItems[2].ToString()` shows you _ListViewItem_ or something similar: if you didn't override `ToString()` method, default behaviour is returning class name...

Comment: @Marco: Yeah, I know. That's why I thought I would be a good idea to explore `songList` through the QuickWatch-Window of the VisualStudio.